# LazyColumn not update when data in LiveData update

Tags: android-jetpack-compose-list

I want to create chat app `U`I using `ViewModel` but when I send button the List in `ViewModel` update but `LayzColumn` not update it data. I don't know why it's not working.

My ChatViewModel

```
class ChatViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private val _messages: MutableLiveData<MutableList<String>> = MutableLiveData(mutableListOf(""))

    val messages: LiveData<MutableList<String>> get() = _messages

    fun add(message: String) {
        _messages.value?.add(message)
        Log.d("Haha", "${_messages.value?.size}")
        _messages.notifyObserver()
    }

}

fun <T> MutableLiveData<T>.notifyObserver() {
    this.value = value
}
```

My LazyColumn

```
val messages by chatViewModel.messages.observeAsState(mutableListOf(""))


LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .weight(1f)
        ) {
            items(messages.toList()) { message ->
                SenderChat(message = message)
            }

        }
```

Comment: have you got the answer

Comment: Hello, I am trying to solve similar thing. Have you got any answers? I think you should remove last "mutableListOf("") when defining val messages in My LazyColumn